# C++でメモリ制限を指定した値にする方法はありますか？

Tags: c++

競技プログラミングでメモリ制限が1024Mとなっていて、これ以上のメモリ使用ができないようにしたいのですが、コンパイラオプションでこれを実現するようなものがありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 単位は M**B** でしょうか？ (正確に記載する癖をつける事をおすすめします)

Comment: 制限したいメモリは何かとか、コンパイラやツールセットを特定した方が答えが出やすいのでは？ [Self-limit heap size in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28653477/9014308)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[unix](/questions/tagged/unix) や [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) では `ulimit -d` ([man bash](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html)) でできるかもしれません。ちなみに [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) では無理でした。
# って書くと「コンパイルオプションで」解決してないじゃんってかみつく人がいそう

Comment: +1 「競技プログラミングでメモリ制限が1024Mとなっていて」もおおむねこの実装なはずなので、同様の制限を行うこの回答が適切でしょうね。「コンパイラオプションでこれを実現するようなもの」という記述がXY問題を引き起こしていますね。

Comment: コンパイラオプションで解決するのではと勝手に予想して質問していたのですが、とても参考になりました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

C++であればメモリ確保・解放は次の4関数に集約されています。

```
void* operator new(size_t size);
void* operator new[](size_t size);
void  operator delete(void* ptr);
void  operator delete[](void* ptr);
```

これらを再定義（内部で`malloc` / `free`を呼ぶといいでしょう）してしまえば、メモリ確保・解放によるメモリ使用量の増減を把握できます。その上で`new`内で独自にメモリ上限を管理することで実現できるかと思います。

ただし、この方法は`malloc`他のメモリ確保には関与できていません。

---

> vector等のライブラリを使うときには難しいかもしれませんが

誤解されています。`std::vector`を含むSTL; 標準テンプレートライブラリやその他の適切に設計されたC++ライブラリは最終的に前述の`new` / `delete`を呼び出すように設計されています。
一例として[`std::vector`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/vector/vector.html)はメモリ操作にテンプレート型引数`Allocator`を使用し、省略時のデフォルト値は[`std::allocator`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/memory/allocator.html)です。このため、`std::vector`が要素を確保する際は[`std::allocator::allocate()`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/memory/allocator/allocate.html)を呼び出します。この関数は

> ストレージは、`::operator new(std::size_t)`の呼び出しによって取得される。

と説明のある通りです。

Comment: なるほどvector等のライブラリを使うときには難しいかもしれませんが、それもありですね。。

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studioのデバッグでメモリ使用量を測定するのでは駄目ですか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
もしコンパイラオプション等でメモリ使用量を測定する機能があったら知りたいという疑問からの質問でした！